# Why would this IF statement not work?

Tags: custom-post-types, conditional-tags, footer

I've placed the following conditional statement in my footer.php file but it isn't working. I want it to show the footer on every page except for single.php and the services.php template:

```
<?php if (!is_single() || !is_page_template('services.php')) {?>
    <footer>Content</footer>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: first try `<?php if(!is_single()) { ?> <footer>Content</footer> <?php } ?>` and let's know what happened.

Comment: Use the `AND` (`&&`) operator

Comment: @PieterGoosen Thanks, that worked perfectly!! If you add it as an answer I will accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `AND` (`&&`) operator to make this work. As your condition stands, it will return true no matter which page you are on. The `OR` operator only needs one true to execute where as the `AND` operator needs all conditions to be true to execute

I just have one other concern here as you are loading your footer conditionally, and that is, you should make sure that you remove `wp_footer()` from that condition, you should not load it conditionally as this will break many scripts that is loaded in the footer. So make sure that you don't load `wp_footer()` conditionally

Comment: No need to worry, the code I'm hiding is literally just HTML5 markup.